# Can a Paladin, Sorcerer, Wizard, and two Druids handle Storm King’s Thunder?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, new-players, party, storm-kings-thunder

I’m somewhat new to D&D and so is the group I’m in. We’re gonna start playing Storm King’s Thunder soon, and I was wondering if we’re gonna have any trouble with our party. We have myself as a Paladin, a Sorcerer, a Wizard, and 2 Druids.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Have you taken the [tour]? This a difficult question to answer as it depends entirely on playstyle. However it may help to give the subclasses each character will take. Also include what particular things you are concerned about. Is this purely a combat effectiveness question? Or an overall party balance for all situations? The second one will be hard to answer. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!